# JQUERY datepicker add custom images to specific date boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

I have a datepicker instance I'm able to highlight and disable specific date ranges:

```
//
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(function(){

      var date1 = new Date;
      date1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
      date1.setDate(10);
      var date2 = new Date;
      date2.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
      date2.setDate(23);

     $("#Reservations_stand_alone_calendar").datepicker({
       changeMonth: true,
       showButtonPanel: false,
       showOtherMonths: true,
       //disabled: true,


       beforeShowDay: function(date){
           return [date.getDay() < 4, date >= date1 && date <= date2 ? "dp-highlight" : ""];
       }

      });

   });
});
```

---

The above is working well highlighting and disabling date ranges.

Now, I would also like to add an image to a specific calendar date box view. I'm Not sure how would I do this. Something like?:

---

```
beforeShowDay: function(date){

     return [date.getDay() < 4, date >= date1 && date <= date2 ? "dp-highlight" : ""];
     // Add image to 21st day??
     if(date ==  21){
       document.getElementById(date).innerHTML += "www.somesitesomewhere.com/Myimage.jpg";??? 
     }

}
```

---

I'm not sure how to access the specific datebox and add the image there

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to get an image to display:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true
  });
});
```

You also want to reference the class/id of the datepicker you wish to target. You may wish to have different images displayed in the background for various datepickers.

Comment: Thanks @iamryandrake :) - But I want the image to show up right on the date. So the 21st day... the box in the calender that holds the number 21 - I want the image to show up there.

Comment: I'm not aware you can do that with this particular plugin, but you could always create a custom calendar or use another calendar library!

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a simple thing to do.
In your CSS add new code:

```css
.dp-highlight-back,
.ui-datepicker .dp-highlight-back span {
  /* INSERT ANY OTHER CSS STYLING HERE USED IN dp-highlight */
  background-image: url("images/calendar.png");
}
```

For a specific date, in your javascript, after calling the datepicker, add this code snippet and add the dates to display the background image to exactly in the format in the sample code below. Multiple dates would be in format: [11, 21, 2018, ""],[12, 21, 2018, ""]

```js
$("#Reservations_stand_alone_calendar").datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: checkForDate
});

function checkForDate(date) {
  var flagDates = [
    [11, 21, 2018]
  ];
  for (i = 0; i < flagDates.length; i++) {
    if (date.getMonth() == flagDates[i][0] - 1 && date.getDate() == flagDates[i][1] && date.getFullYear() == flagDates[i][2]) {
      return [false, "dp-highlight-back", ""];
    }
  }
  return [true];
}
```